# Opening a modal over another one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I use Google App Script with Google Sheets. When I click a button, the code enters in this following function :

```
function myButtonClicked(){
 const template = HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate();

 const html = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput(template)
  .setWidth(500)
  .setHeight(500)
  .setTitle('MyTitle');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'MyTitle');
}
```

My form contains multiple inputs that have an onclick event. This event does something and displays a message in a specific case.

The message is displayed thanks to the following function :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('myMessage');
```

The problem is : when this last one appears, my modal containing my form is closed.

How can I display a modal over another one ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might try displaying your message with a toast

Comment: @Cooper  toasts in GAS?

Comment: Yes look in the spreadsheet documentation. I believe it’s the last command

Comment: I know toasts but it is not sufficiently visible to handle an error message ...

Comment: Perhaps you can run your form as a sidebar?

Comment: You could put the messages into a message div on your main form thus negating the need to run a separate dialog.